# ImportError: cannot import name 'templates' from flask

Tags: python, flask, importerror

Currently I am working on a website, and everything seemed to go all right until I got this error:

[ImportError Command-Line Prompt Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bowTA.png)

```
# lab6_brian_may.py
```

"""This is a simple website program."""

```
# imports
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect, render_template, templates

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../pages/templates')

# base site app route
@app.route('/')
def base_site():
    return render_template(templates + 'base.html')
 return ok

# RPG site app route
@app.route('/RPG', methods=['GET', 'RETURN'])
def RPG_site():
    if request.method == 'RETURN':
        # redirect to base page
        return redirect(url_for('base_site'))
    return render_template(templates + 'RPG.html')
 return ok

# MMO site app route
@app.route('/MMO', methods=['GET', 'RETURN'])
def MMO_site():
    if request.method == 'RETURN':
        # redirect to base page
        return redirect(url_for('base_site'))
    return render_template(templates + 'MMO.html')
 return ok

# First-Person Shooter site app route
@app.route('/First-Person Shooter', methods=['GET', 'RETURN'])
def first_person_shooter_site():
    if request.method == 'RETURN':
        # redirect to base page
        return redirect(url_for('base_site'))
    return render_template(templates + 'First-Person Shooter.html')
return ok
```

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Posting a screen shot of your error makes it difficult for anyone with the same error to find this post.  Please post the text of your error instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `templates` in `flask` module, that is why it raises ImportError.

Flask will look for templates in `templates` folder by default when you call `render_template`.

Have you tried simply changing your `render_template` calls from `return render_template(templates + 'MMO.html')` to `return render_template('MMO.html')`?

Comment: I tried changing the render_template calls like you said, however more errors showed up:

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no pre-built class like templates in Flask. You only need to do the following:

1. Create a directory named templates
2. Add the html file under the
   templates folder.
3. For rendering template, use the
   following code :
   `return render_template('template name.html')`

Comment: When you say to create a directory named templates, do you mean that I create a folder in my file explorer called templates?

Comment: No. Create one as a sub folder in your current working directory. For example, your flask app and other necessary files are created under the directory Flask, create a folder inside    this folder and essentially name it as templates. Your html files goes under this templates folder.